# How to make Kinect depthdata short[] as int for texture formats in shadermodel 3.0?

Tags: c#, xna, kinect

Hi there, we are working on a project with Kinect and C# XNA on Windows7.
We ran into an unexpected problem: the depth data from the Kinect camera gives us a `short[]` but we can only create texture in either `int32` formats or `float16` or `float32` or `float64` formats.

So the problem is converting this fairly large `short[]` image into a `int32` or `float` on the CPU is ridiculously slow. And there's no bitwize operation on Shadermodel 3.0 so we can't bithack the `float` back to an `int` as far as I've understood it.

We're thinking about moving into C++ now but this makes us wonder: how the hell does Xbox360 work with Kinect? It should be optimized for Xbox, we think. Seems silly that there's so few available texture formats.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? The depth data returned by the Kinect isn't an image as such, it's an array of distances. You're going to have to convert it into an image regardless, even if there was some sort of short-based texture format.

Comment: Well in OpenGL we could choose diffrent kinds of texture formats. Example. glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R16, width, height, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (GLvoid*)texture_data); So in C++ and OpenGL we could actually choose to use UNSIGNED_SHORT as input data and conversion would be done for us, fast and optimized. In C# XNA Texture2D SurfaceFormat all formats seems to be float formats... and no automatic conversion available as fast as i can see. Which i feel is strange, since i thought it was optimised for gaming.

Comment: "So in C++ and OpenGL we could actually choose to use UNSIGNED_SHORT as input data and conversion would be done for us, fast and optimized." But how? Those shorts aren't color data. How would OpenGL know what color to convert those values to?

Comment: well because the glTexImage2D function is awesome it allows you to specify what internal format the texture is to be set in and also allows you to specify exactly what format the input data is in. after it is on the graphics card all you need is a shader that does some multiplication